# Vue js load modal content with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm using vue js with laravel, In my page i have 13 modals, I thing it's not a good idea to insert 13 modals in the same page so i put this in my blade :

```
<modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
     <header slot="header" v-html="modalHeader"></header>
     <component slot="body" :is="currentBody"></component>
</modal>
```

And in my file.js i have this :

```
Vue.component('modal', require('./components/Modal.vue'));
Vue.component('StatusModal', require('./components/modals/StatusModal.vue'));
Vue.component('UserModal', require('./components/modals/UserModal.vue'));

const profile = new Vue({
    el: '#profile',
    data: {
        showModal: false,
        modalHeader: '',
        currentBody: '',
    },
    methods: {
        showStatus(){
            this.showModal = true
            this.modalHeader = 'Confirmation'
            this.currentBody = 'StatusModal'

        },
        showUser(){
            this.showModal = true
            this.modalHeader = 'Confirmation'
            this.currentBody = 'UserModal'
        }
    }
})
```

Just for example here i have two modals 'StatusModal' and 'UserModal' and i load them in my js file, so if i have 13 or more modals i will load 13 components in my js file, i need a solution that load only component that i need when i call function, It's possible to load component in function call?

I tried to use ajax and load blade content in ajax call and load it in my modal but i face a problem, i'm using vue validation for inputs so validation don't work (vee-validate) also any vue variable does not compiled and i get {{ variable }} in my modal.

What is the best solution for my case? i appreciate any help

Comment: Are you using vue-cli webpack config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit after chat

Solution found:

**HTML:**

```
<component slot="body" :is="currentBody"></component>
```

**JS:**

```
showStatus() { 
  this.dialog = true 
  System.import('./components/modals/StatusModal.vue').then((response) => { 
    this.currentBody = response
  }); 
},
```

---

### Previous answer

If using vue-cli webpack config(modules), I'd go for a solution as follow. The key point is using `System.import`. It's the same thing as require but asynchronous. It will only resolve one time even if you call the same file multiple times. It'll cache it client side.

I use a [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) here, because it's a lot easier to manage vue *template replacement*.

```
import Modal from './components/Modal.vue'

const profile = new Vue({
  render(h) {
    if (this.showModal) {
      return h('modal', {
        on: {
          close() {
            this.showModal = false
          }
        }
      }, [
        h('header', { slot: 'header' }, this.modalHeader),
        h(this.currentBody, { slot: 'body' })
      ]);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  data: {
    showModal: false,
    modalHeader: '',
    currentBody: {},
  },
  methods: {
    showStatus() {
      this.showModal = true
      this.modalHeader = 'Confirmation'
      this.currentBody = System.import('./components/modals/StatusModal.vue')
    },
    showUser() {
      this.showModal = true
      this.modalHeader = 'Confirmation'
      this.currentBody = System.import('./components/modals/UserModal.vue')
    }
  },
  components: {
    Modal
  }
})
```

Note I haven't tested it. Let me know if anything goes wrong or if I misunderstood your case.

Comment: I will test it and i will inform you, I have a question please if i run showStatus function and import StatusModal component and after i run showUser function and import UserModal component, i will have two imports ? this is not good for performance?

Comment: In this case, you will have 2 loads. That's nothing bad about performance. You just have a light first tick (to display the page) and then load what you *need* at run time. It's a lot better than load everything that you *might need* at first tick. Which would make your users wait more between pages. They might be loading useless components/data.

Comment: You don't mention el: "#app" ?

Comment: You didn't either, I used your template. The is no `el` option because the template is in the `render` function. So no need to point to an element in the DOM to define the template of the component.

Comment: when i delete el: "#app", i get nothing compiled

Comment: You should keep `#app` on your main component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147269/discussion-between-codinga-and-elfayer).